# Ionic Angular Run a schedule notification once

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am building an app that has a service called every 30 minutes to request a value for the remaining units that a client have . During the check , if the client has units lower than the one specified , The app will send a local notification that the units are running low . Everything works fine for this .

The issue i am having is if let's say the client has 90 units and the limit is 100 , The app will send notification fine , but after 30 minutes when it checks again and see that the client has 85 units , it will send again and again until the clients recharges . What i want is the notification to send once .Any help will be appreciated .  Below is my code .

```
this.storage.get('AlertOn100').then((val) => {
      if (val==true){
        if(res.power<100 && res.power>50){
          LocalNotifications.schedule({
            title: "Electricity is below 100 Units",
            text: "Please recharge to avoid running out",
            at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1 * 60 * 1000),
            sound: null
           });
              console.log("Units Below 100 . The guy should be notified")
        }else{
          console.log("Don't send notification at 100 Units because the units are above that value")
        }
      }
       })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a flag to identify notification is sent or not when the app is started save a key into `localstorage` with name `flag` and value will be `false` and when the notification is sent to client successfully you can change the flag to `true` and next time if it it is true don't send notification. this will be working for you replace localStorage with your storage type etc.

```
 this.storage.get('AlertOn100').then((val) => {
  var flag = localStorage.get("flag");
  if (val==true && !flag){
    if(res.power<100 && res.power>50){
      LocalNotifications.schedule({
        title: "Electricity is below 100 Units",
        text: "Please recharge to avoid running out",
        at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1 * 60 * 1000),
        sound: null
       });
       localStorage.set("flag", true);
          console.log("Units Below 100 . The guy should be notified")
    }else{
      console.log("Don't send notification at 100 Units because the units are above that value")
    }
  }
   })
```

and when user recharge set the flag to `false`;

Comment: Hey , Thanks a lot . It works . and sorry for late reply .